# Get real path of selected file in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

What I wanna do is basic. I just want to retrieve the real path of a file instead of `fakepath`.

Here's the explanation:

In `<input type="file">`, For security reasons, browsers do not reveal real path of any selected file. They return a `fakepath`. **But** in chrome extensions, we can access `file://` system with a permission.

Now I have declared that permission in `manifest.json` I just want to know if there is a way to convert `fakepath` to real path.

I know I can use `FileReader` API to get file data but it cannot be used in my case.

Comment: No you cannot. Why do you want to get the real path? What makes the FileReader API unsuitable for your needs?

Comment: If a question is ever "how can I get around this security restriction", it's also your obligation to justify why you need to be able to do this.

Comment: `FileReader` API would be too expensive in terms of computation. As I would need images to be loaded.

Comment: @Teepeemm I need path of selected images to be used in `src`. As compared to this, if I use `FileReader` API wouldn't that be too much considering there is a page refresh every 1 minute?

Comment: Could you show us what you want to do with the FileReader API?  Then maybe we'd be able to see how it could be done with less computation.